# How can I upgrade from CouchDB 0.8.0 to 0.9.0 on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make, couchdb

Ubuntu comes with CouchDB 0.8.0-incubator. I have it running correctly. I've recently wanted to upgrade to 0.9.0, so I followed the instructions on [this blog post](http://blog.james-carr.org/2009/05/01/installing-couchdb-090-on-ubuntu/), but I seem to be missing the final step. I downloaded the tarball, unzipped it, and called make & make install as the guide says. Every step completed successfully. When I then execute

```
/etc/init.d/couchdb start
```

it boots up 0.8.0 instead of 0.9.0. I must be missing some step where my freshly compiled 0.9.0 build replaces the 0.8.0 installation. I thought that's what "make install" would do, but it appears not.

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10 (latest stable) comes with CouchDB 0.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **avelldiroll** mentioned in his comment, Ubuntu 9.10 ships with CouchDB 0.10.0. In the end  I just upgraded my release and used that pre-packaged version. For me it was the easiest option, though I imagine for others that wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.james-carr.org/2009/05/01/installing-couchdb-090-on-ubuntu/) is detailed information how to install CouchDB 0.9.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: That's the same link I included in my original question

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the "make install" step as root?  If not, your regular user account probably can't complete the install steps.

Comment: I ran the compile/make commands with sudo

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already found a solution, but here's an alternative for someone else in a similar situation who can't simply install a new version of the OS.

The packaged version may not put things in the same places as the "make install" defaults, so there's no guarantee that the old version files would get overwritten by the newer files.  When migrating to a newer software version in a package-managed system like Ubuntu, it's best to either

- find packages of the newer version (or create them) to install, so the package manager can update things appropriately, or
- remove the older version from the package manager entirely, and follow the instructions to compile & install the newer package from the source tarball.

I personally prefer to create new packages when possible.  When not possible I tweak the "make install" process to install to `/usr/local` and subdirectories.  (If the software uses a configure script, run `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` to change the default installation location.)  This way the software won't conflict with other files installed by the system package manager.